# Subprocess.Popen reading stdout but execution not finishing

Tags: python, subprocess

Having a few troubles when using subprocess.Popen.

Here is the code I am using:

```
def parse_replay(rep_record):
    rep_path = rep_record['rep_path']
    screp_cmd = f"{cwd}/screp -cmds -mapres -maptiles '{rep_path.replace('..', os.path.dirname(cwd))}'"
    p = subprocess.Popen(screp_cmd, shell=True)
    out = p.stdout.read()
    rep_action_log = json.loads(out)
    return rep_action_log
```

If I use shell=False I get a file not found error.
When using shell=True the command gets executed but the function doesn't return (it keeps listening for the output of the command apparently).

Do you know of any way to be able to capture the stdout of my command whilst correctly finishing the execution of my function?

PS: screp is a CLI that outputs json info to stdout https://github.com/icza/screp

Comment: This doesn't look like a command for which you have any good reason to use `shell=True`, and risk the security bugs that come with it. Why not pass your list of arguments *as a list* so you can use `shell=False`?

Comment: That is: `screp_cmd = [ f"{cwd}/screp", "-cmds", "-mapres", "-maptiles", f"{rep_path.replace('..', os.path.dirname(cwd))}"]`

Comment: That said, being able to capture stdout has nothing to do with `shell=True` or `shell=False`. You can't capture stdout because you aren't passing `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.

Comment: ...ideally, use `subprocess.communicate()`, with all three of `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` explicitly set (_how_ they're set depending on what you _want_ to happen to stderr, and whether you _want_ stdin to be inherited from your Python process itself).

Comment: ...anyhow, for anyone to be able to answer this comprehensively, they'd need to know more about `screp` -- what file descriptors it reads from, what files it writes to and in what order. Ideally, a better [mre] would require only tools people will already have, so folks who don't have this "screp" tool can see the problem themselves.

Comment: Just added info about screp. Tried the stdout=subprocess.PIPE and now the function is finishing its run but returns None. I use shell=True because without it files can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

So Charles' comments work!

First formatting in list of tokens lets you avoid using shell=True.
Second stoud=subprocess.PIPE lets you capture the stdout.

```
def parse_replay(rep_record):
    rep_path = rep_record['rep_path']
    screp_cmd = [f"{cwd}/screp", "-cmds", "-mapres", "-maptiles", f"{rep_path.replace('..', os.path.dirname(cwd))}"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(screp_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.stdout.read()
    rep_action_log = json.loads(out)
    return rep_action_log
```